# Accessing runat="server" control id in WebMethod

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

html code is

```
<script type="text/jscript">
function ajaxcall() {
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "index.aspx/lvimgclick",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: JSON.stringify({ value: "test" }),
     dataType: "json",      
    });
};
</script>

<img src='images/img1.jpg' onclick='return ajaxcall();' />  // calling script

<asp:LinkButton ID="lvlink1" OnClick="lvimg1_Click" CssClass="lv-under" runat="server"  >
<asp:Image ID="lvimg1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/spacer.gif" />

<asp:LinkButton ID="lvlink2" OnClick="lvimg2_Click" CssClass="lv-under" runat="server"  >
<asp:Image ID="lvimg2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/spacer.gif" />

<asp:LinkButton ID="lvlink3" OnClick="lvimg3_Click" CssClass="lv-under" runat="server"  >
<asp:Image ID="lvimg3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/spacer.gif" />

<asp:LinkButton ID="lvlink4" OnClick="lvimg4_Click" CssClass="lv-under" runat="server"  >
<asp:Image ID="lvimg4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/spacer.gif" />
```

.cs code

```
[WebMethod]
public static string lvimgclick()
{      
    return "hi";
}

protected void lvimg1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  

    lvlink1.CssClass = "lv-under";
    lvimg1.ImageUrl = "~/images/1.jpg";

    lvlink2.CssClass = "lv-under";
    lvimg2.ImageUrl = "~/images/spacer.gif";

    lvlink3.CssClass = "lv-under";
    lvimg3.ImageUrl = "~/images/spacer.gif";


    lvlink4.CssClass = "lv-under";
    lvimg4.ImageUrl = "~/images/spacer.gif";
}
```

What want is :

```
[WebMethod]
public static string lvimgclick()
{      
    lvimg1_Click(null, null);
    return "hi";
}
```

or

```
[WebMethod]
public static string lvimgclick()
{      
    lvlink1.CssClass = "lv-under";
    lvimg1.ImageUrl = "~/images/1.jpg";

    lvlink2.CssClass = "lv-under";
    lvimg2.ImageUrl = "~/images/spacer.gif";

    lvlink3.CssClass = "lv-under";
    lvimg3.ImageUrl = "~/images/spacer.gif";


    lvlink4.CssClass = "lv-under";
    lvimg4.ImageUrl = "~/images/spacer.gif";
    return "hi";
}
```

what shall have to do ? Also have to use **lvimg1_Click(null, null);** and **lvlink1.CssClass = "lv-under1";** at many function which are **not to be a webmethod**

Comment: I dont think you can access. All you can do is read from Request and write in Response in webmethod :) How do you call webmethod? using jQuery?

Comment: @Murali any good example?

Comment: @Murali yes i call it using jquery

Comment: If all you need to do is change the CSS of the link, why don't you just change it with jQuery itself, instead of making the webmethod do it thru the server?

Comment: @BeemerGuy do you have any good example? i have never tried ...

Comment: Show your code block that calls the webmethod

Comment: @MiteshJain, see my answer. It may help you

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery you could do like below

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "index.aspx/lvimgclick",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: JSON.stringify({ value: "test" }),
   dataType: "json", 
   success:function(result){

     if(result.cssclass)
     {
       $('#<%= lvlink1.ClientID %>').addClass(result.cssclass);
     }
   }     
  });
```

In WebMethod

```
   public class CustomResult
    {
        public string output{ get; set; }
        public string cssclass{ get; set; }
    }

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static CustomResult lvimgclick()
{      
    var result=new CustomResult{output="hi", cssclass="lv-under1"}

    return result;

}
```

Note:

Sometimes you may need to access the data with `d`, which was added by framework. like `result.d.cssclass`

**EDIT:**

In case if you want to update multiple link buttons, have a common css class defined for it in aspx.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" runat="server" CssClass="menu" Text="Home" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnk2" runat="server" CssClass="menu" Text="AboutUs" />
```

Then in your ajax call's success callback use class selector and update.

```
  success:function(result){

     if(result.cssclass)
     {
       $('a.menu').addClass(result.cssclass);
     }
   }
```

Comment: There you go. Murali beat me to the answer.

Comment: if i have to use 4 linkbutton id than how should i write in this??

Comment: @MiteshJain, Add CssClass property to all 4 link buttons like `CssClass="menu"` and get all 4 in jQuery like `$('a.menu').addClass(result.cssclass)` instead of ID. Or you can add four lines with diff ID and do it. Hope you got it :)

Comment: also Response is showing error in .cs page  Response.ContentType="application/json";

Comment: @MiteshJain, Updated the webmethod as well as ajax call. Please check. Now its simple :)

Comment: also Response is showing error in .cs page Response.ContentType="application/json";

Comment: @MiteshJain, added a new class for customresult. check the complete webmethod signature and code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40721/discussion-between-mitesh-jain-and-murali)