# calling function or server controls in webmethod

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

My html code is

```
<script type="text/jscript">
function ajaxcall() {
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "index.aspx/lvimgclick",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: JSON.stringify({ }),
     dataType: "json",      
    });
};
</script>

<img src='images/img1.jpg' onclick='return ajaxcall();' />  // calling script

<asp:LinkButton ID="lvlink1" OnClick="lvimg1_Click" CssClass="lv-under" runat="server"  >
<asp:Image ID="lvimg1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/spacer.gif" />

<asp:LinkButton ID="lvlink2" OnClick="lvimg2_Click" CssClass="lv-under" runat="server"  >
<asp:Image ID="lvimg2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/spacer.gif" />

<asp:LinkButton ID="lvlink3" OnClick="lvimg3_Click" CssClass="lv-under" runat="server"  >
<asp:Image ID="lvimg3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/spacer.gif" />
```

.cs code

```
[WebMethod]
public static string lvimgclick()
{      
    return "hi";
}

protected void lvimg1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    lvlink1.CssClass = "lv-under1";//another class
    lvimg1.ImageUrl = "~/images/1.jpg";

    lvlink2.CssClass = "lv-under";
    lvimg2.ImageUrl = "~/images/spacer.gif";

    lvlink3.CssClass = "lv-under";
    lvimg3.ImageUrl = "~/images/spacer.gif";

    lvlblhd.CssClass = "detailheader";//label
    lvlblsubhd.CssClass = "detailsubheader";//label
    lvtd.BgColor = "#7e65a9";//td
    lvlblhd.Text = "<img src='images/spacer.gif' height='8px' width='5px' /><br/>Wake up";
    lvlblsubhd.Text = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;to a fragrant day..";
    lvlbl.Text = "A beautifully fragrance residence";
}
```

What I want is :

```
[WebMethod]
public static string lvimgclick()
{      
    lvimg1_Click(null, null);
    return "hi";
}
```

or

```
[WebMethod]
public static void lvimgclick()
{      
    lvlink1.CssClass = "lv-under1";//another class
    lvimg1.ImageUrl = "~/images/1.jpg";

    lvlink2.CssClass = "lv-under";
    lvimg2.ImageUrl = "~/images/spacer.gif";

    lvlink3.CssClass = "lv-under";
    lvimg3.ImageUrl = "~/images/spacer.gif";  

    lvlblhd.CssClass = "detailheader";//label
    lvlblsubhd.CssClass = "detailsubheader";//label
    lvtd.BgColor = "#7e65a9";//td
    lvlblhd.Text = "<img src='images/spacer.gif' height='8px' width='5px' /><br/>Wake up";
    lvlblsubhd.Text = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;to a fragrant day..";
    lvlbl.Text = "A beautifully fragrance residence";    
}
```

what shall I have to do ? I Also have to use **lvimg1_Click(null, null);** and **lvlink1.CssClass = "lv-under1";** at many function which are **not to be a webmethod**

I am new so please make me know if you want many more information

Comment: According to me you cannot call the server controls in a web method....

Comment: it can be done , but dont know the actual way

Comment: Your webmethod takes no arguments, but your Ajax call is calling it with value:test. Remove this from the call and you should hit the webmethod.

Comment: @christiandev thats not the issue, the problem is how shall i call the linkbutton in to webmethod

Comment: it was **an** issue though, as that would not work, hence the edit I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done only on moment request. You can create server control object in static method and change them, but if you want that changes was apply to client, you need add client code for process string from server response.
So usually you can skip server side method and do all on client at once

**UPDATE**
If you need only change css class and image url you don't need ajax and web method, all it you can do in client at once like this

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    function imgclick() {
        $('#<%= lvlink1.ClientID %>').removeClass().addClass("lv-under1"); //another class
        $('#<%= lvimg1.ClientID %>').attr('src','<%= ResolveUrl("~/images/1.jpg") %>');

        $('#<%= lvlink2.ClientID %>,#<%= lvlink3.ClientID %>').addClass("lv-under");
        $('#<%= lvimg2.ClientID %>, #<%= lvimg3.ClientID %>').attr('src', '<%= ResolveUrl("~/images/spacer.gif") %>');
    };
</script>

<img src='images/img1.jpg' onclick='return imgclick();' />  // calling script

<asp:LinkButton ID="lvlink1" OnClick="lvimg1_Click" CssClass="lv-under" runat="server"  >
<asp:Image ID="lvimg1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/spacer.gif" />

<asp:LinkButton ID="lvlink2" OnClick="lvimg2_Click" CssClass="lv-under" runat="server"  >
<asp:Image ID="lvimg2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/spacer.gif" />

<asp:LinkButton ID="lvlink3" OnClick="lvimg3_Click" CssClass="lv-under" runat="server"  >
<asp:Image ID="lvimg3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/spacer.gif" />
```

if use this case - don't need web methods

**UPDATE2**

```
function imgclick() {
    ...
    $('#<%= lvlblhd.ClientID %>').removeClass().addClass("detailheader").html("<img src='images/spacer.gif' height='8px' width='5px' /><br/>Wake up")
    $('#<%= lvlblsubhd.ClientID %>').removeClass().addClass("detailsubheader").html("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;to a fragrant day..");
    $('#<%= lvtd.ClientID %>').css('background-color',"#7e65a9");//td
    $('#<%= lvlbl.ClientID %>').text("A beautifully fragrance residence");
    ...
}
```

Comment: found same question and has read but cant understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832028/accessing-runat-server-control-id-in-webmethod

Comment: @Xtremcool what not work? you have a error or class not applied?

Comment: i have applied the imgclick() script in my ajaxcall() script but the cssclass and image is not getting change

Comment: @Xtremcool, you try my code, or merge your code and my? if merge can you provide finish code?

Comment: hey your code is working, can u also help me how  to insert text in label and how to change the bgcolor of td

Comment: somethig like this: `$('#yourlabelid').text('newtext'); $('td').css('background-color','newcolor');`

Comment: if i want to write in text <img src='images/spacer.gif' height='8px' width='5px' /><br/>Wake Up.................than how shall i write like this?...see lvlblhd.Text to my edited question....here this text is leaving the upper spacing

Comment: if i want to write in text <img src='images/spacer.gif' height='8px' width='5px' /><br/>Wake Up.................than how shall i write like this?...see lvlblhd.Text to my edited question....here this text is leaving the upper spacing

Comment: $('#<%= lvtd.ClientID %>').attr('BgColor', '#7e65a9'); your td

Answer (score 0):

From what i know you can't manipulate server controls with WebMethods, you could use Update Panels if you don't want to do a full postback of the page.

Here is an overview of Update Panels in MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx