# Calling Server controls and function in web method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have server control says Link button and I want to use that control in **web method function** and also use that *server control (Link button)* in a function, which are not suppose to be a web method.

### **HTML code is**

```
<script type="text/jscript">
function ajaxcall() {
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "index.aspx/lvimgclick",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     data: JSON.stringify({ value: "test" }),
     dataType: "json",      
    });
};
</script>

<img src='images/img1.jpg' onclick='return ajaxcall();' />  // calling script

<asp:LinkButton ID="lvlink1" OnClick="lvimg1_Click" CssClass="lv-under" runat="server"  >
<asp:Image ID="lvimg1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/spacer.gif" />

<asp:LinkButton ID="lvlink2" OnClick="lvimg2_Click" CssClass="lv-under" runat="server"  >
<asp:Image ID="lvimg2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/spacer.gif" />

<asp:LinkButton ID="lvlink3" OnClick="lvimg3_Click" CssClass="lv-under" runat="server"  >
<asp:Image ID="lvimg3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/spacer.gif" />
```

### **.cs code**

```
[WebMethod]
public static void lvimgclick()
{      

}

protected void lvimg1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lvlink1.CssClass = "lv-under1"; // Another class
    lvimg1.ImageUrl = "~/images/1.jpg";

    lvlink2.CssClass = "lv-under";
    lvimg2.ImageUrl = "~/images/spacer.gif";

    lvlink3.CssClass = "lv-under";
    lvimg3.ImageUrl = "~/images/spacer.gif";
}
```

### **What I want is** :

```
[WebMethod]
public static void lvimgclick()
{      
    lvimg1_Click(null, null);        
}
```

or

```
[WebMethod]
public static void lvimgclick()
{      
    lvlink1.CssClass = "lv-under";
    lvimg1.ImageUrl = "~/images/1.jpg";

    lvlink2.CssClass = "lv-under";
    lvimg2.ImageUrl = "~/images/spacer.gif";

    lvlink3.CssClass = "lv-under";
    lvimg3.ImageUrl = "~/images/spacer.gif";      
}
```

*What shall I have to do ?*

I also have to use **lvimg1_Click(null, null);** and **lvlink1.CssClass = "lv-under1";** at many other function which are **not to be a webmethod**

Comment: duplicate [calling function or server controls in webmetod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19899664/calling-function-or-server-controls-in-webmetod) and [Accessing runat=“server” control id in WebMethod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832028/accessing-runat-server-control-id-in-webmethod)

Comment: @Grundy ok get that ,,,but what the javascript to change label text

Comment: something like `$('#yourlabelid').text('newtext')`