# how to access html control in static function (Asp.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asmx, webmethod

I m trying to access html controls on my static function but i m getting complie time error 
so please give me the solution

here is my code

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]    
public static void btnPostNote_Click(string note)
{
    string borrowerId = Data.QueryString("id");

    note = "";
    RefreshNotes(borrowerId);
    lblNoteSaved.Text = "Note Successfully Saved
}
```

---

and i tried the below solution so i got the null pointer exception

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static void btnPostNote_Click(string note)
{
   if (HttpContext.Current != null)
   {
     Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
     Label lblNoteSaved = (Label)page.FindControl("lblNoteSaved");
     string borrowerId = Data.QueryString("id");

     note = "";
     RefreshNotes(borrowerId);
     lblNoteSaved.Text = "Note Successfully Saved";                
   }
}
```

Comment: You won't get controls in Web Methods. Web Methods behave like stateless API. ViewState data is not posted back to server in this case. So answer is simply You Can't.

Comment: However, You can pass data from client (browser) to that WebMethod.

Comment: so how can i do this , please give the another way

Comment: through which it is possible

Comment: Use jquery ajax to call web methods. Ex. http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: Can you please tell us ..Why you want to access `Controls of webpage` in `webmethod` .. so that we can help you providing `different way of solution` to accomplish it....

Comment: are you using ajax? paste that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use AJAX and JQuery for that these 3 links will help you

[Accessing runat="server" control id in WebMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832028/accessing-runat-server-control-id-in-webmethod)

[http://forums.asp.net/t/1580317.aspx?Access+Server+control+in+web+method+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19832028/accessing-runat-server-control-id-in-webmethod)

http://www.itorian.com/2012/07/calling-aspnet-c-method-web-method.html

Comment: @Rashi Gupta If it helps you please mark it as answer